# ag-grid: JavaScript Grid get row id

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am testing ag-grid and trying to get a row id when clicking on a row. I can see the value, but not retrieve it.

[image: row id from ag-grid]

There is no clue in the documentation. Any tip how to retrieve the data?

Comment: Try reading post_id like - this.data['post_id'].value

Comment: Thank you, but: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post_id' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ag-grid website](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/row-selection/#example-single-row-selection) can you use the selectionChanged event, find the selected rows and from there you can access the associated data?

```
<ag-grid-angular>
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```
onSelectionChanged() {
  const selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
  const selectedId = selectedRows[0].id;
}
```

See this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/lfjvlLlbyixDOo6m

I've just reread your question and I didn't see you want to use rowClicked.  Try this example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/lfjvlLlbyixDOo6m

```
onRowClicked(params)
{
  console.log(params)
  const clickedItem = <dataItem>params.data;
  console.log(clickedItem.athlete)
}
```

ie cast the item appropriately before using it.

Comment: Thank You! This worked:   onRowClicked(params){alert(params.data.post_id)}